# Relationship between square of adjacency matrix and Laplacian matrix

Tags: matrices, graph-theory, graph-laplacian, adjacency-matrix

Consider a simple undirected graph with $n$ elements. Let $A$ be the adjacency matrix of the graph with elements $a_{ij}$. Let $L$ be the graph Laplacian with $L=D-A$ where $D$ is the degree matrix. Let $N_i$ be the neighbor set of agent $i$.

I did some sample graphs and I see that

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \left[\sum_{j\in N_i} (y_i-y_j) \right]^2 = y^T(2L)y$$

I was hoping to see $y^TL^TLy$ but it never seemed to be the case. Why and when is the above condition true?

Comment: Are you sure you want to square the sum?

Comment: Since $a_{ij} \in \{0,1\}$, are you sure you need to include it?

Comment: Yes, its a part of a bigger equation. My question is why the square of elements of the adjacency matrix results in 2L and not L^2. Is it because of the symmetry?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo even if I do not include $a_{ij}$ the result is the same.

Comment: Please note that the square includes the inner summation

Comment: You are right. I don't need $a_{ij}$ here for this particular case. I have included it for the sake of completeness and in case I decide to add weights. However, the question remains the same, why is $$\sum_{i=1}^n \left[\sum_{j\in N_i} (y_i-y_j) \right]^2 = y^T(2L)y$$

Comment: I don't have a lot of trust in your claim.

Comment: Why not? What would it rather be?

Comment: Working with sums is a mess.  Try to use the signed incidence matrix, $C$, which is an $m \times n$ matrix, where $m$ is the number of edges.  $C y$ is the $m$-vector containing all the subtractions.

Comment: I told you that working with sums is a mess.  Think of the vector $C y$ and what to do with it. What do you want? All squared subtractions?

Comment: Yes, I need a matrix to represent the squared subtractions across the graph

Comment: A matrix or a vector? Why not use $\| C y \|_2^2$?